# Можно ли (и если да то как) внести изменения в JSON массив только измененного значения не пересобирая массив заново?

Tags: php, json

Суть такая: У пользователя есть разные опции в аккаунте. Пользователь что-то выбрал в каждой опции и я записал все опции в бд.

```
$array = [
  'option_1' => '1',
  'option_2' => '2',
  'option_3' => '3'
];

$database->update('users',['user_option[JSON]' => $array],[
  'id' => $user_id
]);

//Далее пользователь решил что-то изменить и прислал другое значение одной из опций.
$newValue = '444';

//Достаю его опции
$user_option = $database->get('users','user_option[JSON]',[
  'id' => $user_id
]);

//Получаю
Array
(
    [option_1] => 1
    [option_2] => 2
    [option_3] => 3
)

//Теперь нужно изменить
[option_1] => 1 на  [option_1] => 444

//Не хочу делать так
$newarray = [
  'option_1' => $newValue,
  'option_2' => $user_option['option_2'],
  'option_3' => $user_option['option_3']
];

$database->update('users',['user_option[JSON]' => $newarray],[
  'id' => $user_id
]);
```

Есть ли способ изменить только `'option_1' => $newValue` не переписывая все опции, т.к их может быть несколько десятков.
Спасибо!

Comment: и что вам мешает сделать `$user_option['option_1'] = $newValue` ?

Comment: а просто нельзя сделать а-ля `->update('users', ['user_option[JSON][option_id] => $newVlaue])`

Comment: Нет так не работает. в запросе```['user_option[JSON]```это столбец а дальше уже WHERE ```id=>$user_id``` https://medoo.in/api/update здесь есть пример но я его и использую выше чтобы записать всё а вот как обновить что-то одно не понятно.

Comment: Если я сделаю просто ```$user_option['option_1'] = $newValue``` то он один и запишется в поле очистив все остальное. Если опций будет 30-40 то это 60-80 строк все поля вытаскивать и снова собирать в массив или форычем. Но мне кажется есть вариант как то проверять только измененные значения, пропуская те что не изменены и перезаписывать их.

Answer (score 0):

Не указан движок БД. Если это MySQL, то можно воспользоваться "сырыми" запросами для обновления информации. И составлять, собственно, нужные.

К примеру:

1. [Тут про сырые запросы](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)
2. [Тут про частичное обновление JSON-данных](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/partial-update-of-json-values/)

Конечно нужно смотреть еще версию движка БД, чтобы таковая возможность поддерживалась.

Comment: Это MySQL фреймворк Medoo.in

Comment: Да по второй ссылке информация искомая осталось только все это сделать не отходя от синтаксиса фреймворка. Написал разработчикам может чего подскажут, что врядли.)

Comment: Я же написал - нужно изыскать возможность запуска "сырых" запросов. Не факт что во фрэймворке это есть (это реализовано), а "сырой" запрос порешает.